# Check the render method of `App`. Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Не могу понять в чем именно ошибка,приложение работает но в консоли это

> **Warning**: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of App

```
    function App() {
  return (
    <div className="mainBox">
      {items.map((obj) => (
        <Pizza tittle={obj.tittle} imageUrl={obj.imageUrl} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Возможно в консоли больше информации? Может там есть что то про key для списков? )

Comment: Да,вот полное сообщение 
"react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `App`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at Pizza (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111:5)
    at App"

Answer (score 0):

В **React** списки должны иметь уникальные ключи. Это позволяет react.js более точечно управлять содержимым.

Для задания ключей, передаем в компонент(или html тег) атрибут `key`.

Можно сделать ключ как номер индекса массива:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="mainBox">
      {items.map((obj, idx) => (
        <Pizza key={idx} tittle={obj.tittle} imageUrl={obj.imageUrl} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Если ваш `obj` содержит, допустим, уникальный `id`, то это будет лучшим решением:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="mainBox">
      {items.map(obj => (
        <Pizza key={obj.id} tittle={obj.tittle} imageUrl={obj.imageUrl} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```