# Посты добавляются и и данные обновляются, но посты добавляются без "id", из за этого появляется предупреждение, что нет ключа у дочерних элементов

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

Новые посты добавляются и данные на странице обновляются. но посты добавляются без "id", хотя `POST` запрос возвращает с "id"
`{ "title": "ewewerewr", "body": "werwerwer", "id": 101 }` 
По причине того что, новые добавленные посты в списке без `id` получаю предупреждение что нет ключа у дочерних элементов,  не могу понять в чем причина, если кто то может подсказать, то буду благодарен.

```
const form = useForm<Posts>()
const { register, control, handleSubmit, formState, reset } = form
const { errors } = formState;

const create = useMutation({
    mutationFn: addPosts,
    onMutate: async (newPost) => {
        await queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ["posts"] })

        const previousPosts = queryClient.getQueryData(["posts"]) as Posts[]

        queryClient.setQueryData<Posts[]>(["posts"], (old) => [...(old || []), newPost])

        return () => queryClient.setQueriesData(["posts"], previousPosts)
    }
})


const submit = (post: Posts) =>{
    console.log(post)

    create.mutate(post)
    reset();
};
```

`POST` запрос

```
    export const addPosts = async (post: Posts) => {
       return apiClient.post(`/posts?_limit=7`, post);
    };
```

рендер компонента

```
const PostCard = () =>{
const { data, error, isLoading} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["posts"],
    queryFn: getAllPosts,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false
});

if(error) return <p>Error!</p>
if(isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>

return (
    <ul className="post-card">
        {data?.map((post) => (
            <li  className="post-card__item" key={post.id}>
                <p className="post-title">{post.title}</p>
                <p className="post-body">{post.body}</p>
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
)
```

};

export default PostCard;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите сам рендер компонента

Comment: @SwaD добавил, если вы это имели ввиду

Comment: Судя по скрину, такое ощущение, что к вам в ответе id не приходит. Например в п.7 я не вижу этого поля. Если это так, то надо либо править бэк, либо костылить на клиенте например так: `map((post, idx) => ( .... key={'${post.id}-${idx}'} ... )`

Comment: @SwaD -  предупреждение пропало, но можете пожалуйста  обьяснить суть такого подхода, хочу понять почему при таком подходе не вывело предупреждение?

Comment: При рендере списка, реакт требует, что бы ключи были уникальными. Если вы сделали из примера выше, то у вас ключи заведомо уникальны, т.к. в них сидит индекс элемента массива. Там где нет id, у вас ключ получается *-7*(к примеру), а до этого были пустышки и ключи становились не уникальными.

Comment: @SwaD - спасибо! , теперь понятно, где вам тут лайк поставить?

Comment: Решение костыльное и далеко не самое правильное, т.к. реакт по данным ключам пытается менять только изменения. Из-за мешанины в ключах, могут быть баги при отрисовке списков в виде дублей строк. Оформлять такое ответом не хочется. Рад был помочь. А вам советую разобраться с ответами сервера и опираться на реальный id элемента, а не на индекс элемента массива.

Comment: А оказывается, я уже [давал ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1498578/check-the-render-method-of-app-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key/1498587#1498587) на такой вопрос

Comment: @SwaD - там в примере как бы вообще не указаны ключи, а в моем примере ключей нет только у новых добавленных постов, как по вашему будет если указать сразу при созданий поста рандомный айди, добавлю как ответ. посмотрите если вам не сложно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

насколько правильно такой подход и как сделать так чтоб потом заменить
этот id с id который приходит с респонса

```
const submit = (post: Posts) =>{
    post.id = Math.random()
    if(post.id)
        console.log(post)
    
        create.mutate(post)
    reset();
};**
```

Comment: Это то же самое, что и с индексом массива(примерно). Работать будет, однако могут быть побочные явления